# Disable only one item in a wxpython.listbox

Tags: listbox, wxpython

I am trying to disable only one item in a listbox with wxpython. I already searched in the Internet for a way to do this, but I found nothing...

I hope you can give me a hint!

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"? The idea of a listbox is to allow the user to select an item from it. Are you wanting to prevent the selection of a particular item?

Comment: With 'disable' I mean, that the user can't click on one of the items. the other items should be clickable. Sorry for my bad english, I don't know how to say it correct :|

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a direct way to do this, so the only way would be to do it by hand: catch click events, use the `HitTest` to find which item was selected, and then ignore the event if it's the "deactivated" item.  (Tree Controls have the `EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGING` which would be useful here, but there's no analog for a ListBox afaik.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind to wx.EVT_LISTBOX and check if the selection is in your "deactivated" list. If so, set the selection to a different item in the control.